# How do I add an overlay that does not move with the map to a GMSMapView?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I'm trying add a crosshair in the middle of a `GMSMapView`. The crosshair will not move with the map as the user pans it. It will move with the camera.

I looked at the google maps guide but it doesn't seem to talk about the kind of overlays I'm interested in. What it says is just adding overlays and shapes that moves with the map.

Therefore, I tried to come up with something on my own.  I tried to add an `UIImageView` on top of the map view he storyboard. (Note that both the image view and the map view is in the storyboard and they are both direct subviews of the `view` that the VC controls)

[image]

When I run the app, I did not see the crosshair anywhere on the map. I looked at the UI hierarchy and saw this:

[image]

The little view is the image view with the crosshair, and as you can see there are 3 more views in front of it. I think this is why the crosshair did not show. The three views are, from right to left: `GMSVectorMapView`, `GMSUISettingsPaddingView` and `GMSUISettingsView`.

I have not idea how to bring the image view to front. I tried bring it to front by calling `bringSubview(toFront:)`. I tried to call this in both `viewDidLoad` and `viewDidAppear` but it did nothing in both times.

How can I make such an overlay work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use zPosition to achieve this

```
YourView.layer.zPosition = 1
```

by doing this you will put your view's layer to the frontmost position, but not the view itself. So position of the view won't change.

```
self.view.bringSubview(toFront: YourView)
```

Should also work, it's probably juat a timing problem.

Comment: Great! It worked! However, your answer currently seems like a comment. Can you add a bit ore explanation to explain why this works but using `bringSubview(toFront:)` doesn't?

Comment: I don't think it's a timing problem though. I tried to trigger the call with a button press. I pressed the button after everything is loaded in but it did not do anything. When do you think I should call it?

Comment: Can you show the code sample and the view hierarchy with the tree?

Comment: Here is the repo: https://github.com/Sweeper777/TimeZoneHelper/tree/master/TimeZoneHelper

Comment: Crosshair should be subview of self.view not the map

Comment: Oh I noticed it just now! Thank you!